# Is there a faster than O(N^2) way to find all unique elements in a distance matrix corresponding to an ultrametric space?

Tags: matrix, time-complexity

Consider a $N\times N$ matrix $A$ with the following properties

-$A$ is symmetric
-$A(i,i)=0$ for all $i \in {1,...,n}$
-$A(i,j) \leq \max (A(i,k),A(k,j))$ for all $i,j,k\in {1,...,n}$ (ultrametric inequality)

For those of you who are familiar with ultrametric spaces, $A$ is the distance matrix for an ultrametric space. The question then is

Is there a way to find all unique elements of such a matrix $A$ without having to check all $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ entries in the upper half of the matrix? Is there a special name for this particular type of problem?

I suspect the answer is no, due to the following examples.

-Consider a matrix $A$ such that all off diagonal entries are some $a>0$. Then the only way to find all unique values would be to check every entry, since the ultrametric inequality will never help us.

-Consider a matrix $A$ such that all off diagonal entries are some $a>0$ except for $A(i,j)=A(j,i)=b, j>i$ with $0<b<a$. Then such a matrix will still satisfy the conditions above. I suspect this would still take O(N^2)$ to ascertain that the only unique values are $a$ and $b$ since knowing all $A(p,q)$ with $q>p, (q,p) \neq (i,j)$ would not help us ascertain that $A(i,j)=b$.

Any thoughts, references or answers would be greatly appreciated.